# Using 'bait tags' to discourage shopping / subjective questions?

Tags: discussion, tags, subjective-warning

There's already warnings on new posts about how a question might get closed if you use certain words.

However, on Travel.SE at least, we still get a lot of "I want to go to Europe for 3 weeks, where should I go?"-style subjective questions, and "What's the best tour?" and "What's the most interesting cellphone I can buy in America?".  These are subjective/shopping/advice/open and are almost always closed.

So, one user, uncovery, [suggested Bait Tags](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1349/how-about-bait-tags) (their words), where if people try and tag their questions as 'recommendation' or 'advice' or 'shopping' as some are prone to doing, we could include phrases in the tags along the lines of 'be very careful, read the FAQ, this is likely to be closed'.

Of course, they may ignore it, or just not tag with those tags, which is annoying, and it's also a hack, so I wondered if there was a better way, or if people on other sites have had similar thoughts / attempts / solutions ?

Comment: The [books](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/books) tag on SO is an example of that sort of "technique". It does not work.

Comment: What if, instead of warning the user, the presence of the tag weighed into the 'this question is low quality and cannot be posted' filter?

Comment: I would not include the warning in the tag but rather have a proper pop-up or similar graphic telling the user very explicitly that the current question is bad.

Comment: One problem we run into with tag usage on Arqade is, "Well, the tag exists, that means I can use it!", and thereby equating tag validity to question validity.

Comment: @Mat When you attempt to create a question with the [tag:books] tag, all it does is prevent you from creating the question with that tag - it doesn't explain *why* this tag is not allowed. Adding a link to the FAQ here might help a little.

Answer (score 5):

**Signposts are only useful if people bother reading them.**  Most people won't bother until it's too late.

I would find this technique to be pretty pointless, considering the sheer volume of questions on SO, and the amount of users coming into the system, asking questions that fall into "shopping-esque" categories.

The only real way to get the message across is to close/remove the question, making the point that this type of question is *explicitly* discouraged.